# Tree suggestion for shade but in pot

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, containers, sunlight, shade

I am looking to grow a tree to have some shade on my roof in the summer. I can only plant it in a pot (not in ground), it will be a 20 gallon pot.

Can you give me a suggestion which tree to grow? It gets very hot weather full sun 42c (107F) here. It should give shade at least 4 feet around it.

Would love if it is a fruit tree, but not necessary.

One idea I already have is Fig. But I already have a fig tree, and want something new.

Comment: Bearing in mind your summer ambient temperatures, you are clearly not in the UK lol. It might help others if you can specify approximately where you live in the world and if you are approximately at sea level of at a higher altitude and what rainfall do you expect per month please? How harsh are your winters? If you can edit your post to include a pic of your prospective garden location, I am sure it would help a great deal. many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nikki I am from Pakistan. We mostly have lengthy hot summar. Recently there have been rains often, but in past years, rain was rare. But there is no shortage of tap water.

Comment: [This](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/63416/1316) post of mine explains how easy it is to construct a large pot out of Ytong.

Answer (score 2):

Any trees that naturally go in Pakistan should be fine.  Visit a garden center or nursery and see what they have on sale.

When I google it, I see that these flourish there

- apple
- pear
- peach
- plum

I wouldn't advise mango as it needs t be large to produce much fruit.

Comment: I am thinking to go with persimmon.